# Grails 3.0.1 development environment

Tags: grails, ide

I am looking for some opinions on a good combination of tools to develop a Grails 3.0.1 application. I tried IntelliJ 14.1.3 but it's still very buggy so Grails 3.0.1 support is not yet completely supported.

I'm developing on a Mac OS X 10.10.3.

Creating a Grails application using commandline tools is no problem, but finding a good IDE compatible with Grails 3.0.1 seems not so easy.

My question: which IDE is preferable for Grails 3.0.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I think IntelliJ is your best bet at the moment (also mentioned in the [docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/gettingStarted.html#ide). GGTS only supports 2.x, and probably won't ever support Grails 3.

Comment: Safe to say that GGTS won't support Grails 3 as there won't be any new GGTS releases

Comment: Oh my!  No other option, tears :(  Sublime is still my best though